# Is there a way to create a list that would work as a counter?

Tags: python, arrays, list, counter

I'm trying to create a list that works as a counter, such as every time an event happens, a number is added to it to keep track of how often it occurs. It would work as an index towards a list more or less.

I'm new to python, which is why some may see my code as spaghetti-code.

I have my main class calling for an array class that's 0-50 indexes long to create an object of it. It also initiates the counter with the value 0 for the object as seen below.

```
def __init__(self):
    self._table = Array((0,), (50,))
    self._counter = 0
```

I run this method, taking the value of `key` and `obj`, to populate the array object. However, when entering the parameters to the method `enter_value()`, it gives the error saying that `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

```
def populate_test(self, key, obj):
    for i in range(len(self._table._array)):
        self._table.enter_value(self._counter, (key, obj))
        self._counter = self._counter + 1
```

This is the *enter_value* method.

```
def enter_value(self, index, value):
    for i in range(len(self._table._array)):
         ###Here's where the error occurs
         if (index[i] < self._low[i]) or (index[i] > self._high[i]):
             //Do something
```

From what I've learned, a subscriptable object is something that works as a list or dictionary. Does my error occur because of the `index[i]` since my counter is an `int` object and not actually a list? If that's the case, as to my question regarding this post, is there a way for me to create the list that would work as a counter that's better?

Comment: *"such as every time an event happens, a number is added to it to keep track of how often it occurs"* ...this is an XY problem. You need to tell us about the task you are trying to solve, instead of asking something about how you think you could solve it. What kind of event? What needs to be counted, and why? What do you want to achieve overall?

Comment: self.counter is int in your code. Error is due to index[i] when passed to enter_value( index= self.counter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, your error occurs because your `self._counter` variable is an `int`

if you want to have a list as a counter you can use:

```
self._counter = [0]
```

each time you want to increment the counter you can do:

```
self._counter.append(self._counter[-1] + 1)
```

self._counter[-1] is your actual counter value

Answer (score 2):

The error is being raised because the value you are passing into self._table.enter_value as index is self._counter, which is an integer, not a list, and therefore not subscriptable.